# Layout for 720x1280 phone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I am using the emulator to test the screen layout for [Motorola Razr phone](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Motorola-XT928_id6957) at Landscape mode.

The phone dimensions are not common like other phones and so I am getting smaller layout with respect to the screen size of the phone.

- Physical size:  *4.5 inches*
- Resolution:     *720 x 1280 pixels*
- Pixel density:  *326 ppi*

I already have folders for handling multiple size tablets and phones in res folder -

- *layout*
- *layout-large*
- *layout-large-land*
- *layout-large-land-tvdpi*
- *layout-sw600dp-land*
- *layout-xlarge*

So the phone (Motorola Razr) is using layout folder xml to display the contents but this is small enough for the phone resolution.

What should be the layout folder for this phone specification ?

If I create `layout-sw720dp` folder and put the layout file there, the application still takes layout file from `layout`.

If I create `layout-w720-h1280` folder then I gets compile time error after creation with red cross mark on this folder.

The post [new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html?m=1) mentions -

**Typical numbers for screen width dp are:**

320: *a phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).*

480: *a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).*

600: *a 7” tablet (600x1024).*

720: *a 10” tablet (720x1280, 800x1280, etc).*

But then my device is not a 10” tablet but a 4.5 inch phone so that to use the smallest dp value.

**UPDATE:**

The `Motorola Razr` phone is a `xhdpi` device, so I have to divide a pixel-based dimension by 2 to get the dimension in dp. So the Motorola Razr is `640dp` tall, and `360dp` wide.

> layout-sw720dp - Wrong folder.
>
> layout-sw360dp - Right folder.

With the above statement in account I created a `layout-sw360dp` folder and kept my layout files there. Now the application is successfully taking the layout files from this folder to show **for this device**.

But now, another problem arises. My **7' tablet device** is also taking layout files from this folder instead of **layout-large-land** from where it was taking the layout files previously.

So again this idea dropped!

Any help....

Comment: your device is **large** and **xhdpi**

Comment: Usually, separate layout is needed when you have bigger screen size(inches). If it is 4.5" phone then I would expect to use regular layout which lay out views using DP dimensions. If it's a problem with images you have to supply different bitmap versions. For this device drawable-xhdpi is correct.

Comment: @Loop - I have put the layouts in different layout folders and drawables in different drawable folders. Since I am dealing with layout so how can I put in `drawable-xhdpi` ? Isn't there any layout folder for this device compatibility ?

Comment: What is your minimum Android supported version?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein - My other 7' phone ([asus_memo_pad](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_memo_pad_me172v-5249.php)) is 600 x 1024 pixels. The link where you accidentally landed yesterday is the same link that I posted in my question above :) . But that is another choice to prepare one more folder for my ASUS Memo Pad. Will look for that too.

Comment: @Loop -  `android:minSdkVersion="8"`

Comment: If you need to pick bigger layout only in landscape mode then try layout-w600dp.

Comment: Old but might help others. I explicitly created a layout i.e layout-540x888 for motorola phones as there layout is say totally out of the world. Check out how you can define a layout for particular screen explicitly.